# 'module' object is not callable sgd

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Here is my code.

```
from keras.optimizers import gradient_descent_v2 as SGD

sgd=SGD(lr=0.01,momentum=0.9,decay=(0.01/25),nesterov=False)
```

I get the following error when I try to run it.

```
----> 1 sgd=SGD(lr=0.01,momentum=0.9,decay=(0.01/25),nesterov=False)
       

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with tensorflow `tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9, decay=1e-6, nesterov=False)`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use the `gradient_descent_v2` to import SGD optimizer.

Now, [SGD](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/SGD)(Stochastic Gradient Descent) optimizer inherits from **tf.keras.optimzers**, which you can import by giving it's exact alias name as below:

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD

sgd=SGD(learning_rate=0.01,momentum=0.9,decay=(0.01/25),nesterov=False)
```